# Can't find [WebInvoke] and [WebGet]

Tags: wcf, webget, webinvoke

I can't find `[WebInvoke]` and `[WebGet]`. I have already add *System.ServiceModel* reference. what is the problem? I use .NET Framwork 4

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll`. Notice that you need to target the full .NET Framework (either 3.5 or 4.0) - if your application is targeting the *client profile* for those frameworks, this assembly won't be available.

Comment: thanx I think it was the problem

Comment: Not having any luck with mine - I am trying to convert a Silverlight 4 --> Silverlight 5 under .NET 4.5.2 - I have added the System.ServiceModel.Web.dll , still no luck... thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Need to add the reference `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll` and import the namespace `System.ServiceModel.Web` by using below statement
`using System.ServiceModel.Web;` Then it will work.

Comment: This helped me more than the accepted answer, because it mentions the correct using directive. My DLL reference was OK, but i was missing the using directive (my code was copied from a tutorial). I vote this up.

Answer (score 0):

When using attributes "Attribute" portion of the class is implied.

WebInvoke - [WebInvokeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.aspx)

WebGet - [WebGetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx)